# How to retrieve Playlist from iPod Library in iOS?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I am trying to retrieve playlist from iPod Library with `MPMediaQuery` in iOS.
And i want to show in `UITableView`.

Here is my codes in `viewDidLoad`.

```
MPMediaQuery *myQuery = [[MPMediaQuery alloc] init];
[myQuery setGroupingType: MPMediaGroupingPlaylist];
arrayOfPlaylist = [myQuery collections];
```

And In `UITableViewCell` Method

```
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    for(int i=0;i<self.arrayOfPlaylist.count;i++)
    {
        dic = [self.arrayOfPlaylist objectAtIndex:0];
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10];
        cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self.arrayOfPlaylist objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    }

    return cell;
```

After I write above codes , in my `UITableView` I only got following messages:

```
<MPConcreteMediaPlaylist : 0x1e51afd0>
```

I don't know what is that and how to convert playlist name into String.
When I test with `NSLog` method , my playlist count is correct.

But I only got the above message and no playlist name in `UITableView`.

I am just a beginner in iOS.

Please help me to show playlist in `UITableView`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got my answer for my own question.

here is it.

```
MPMediaQuery *query = [MPMediaQuery playlistsQuery]; 
NSArray *playlists = [query collections];

for(int i = 0; i < [playlists count]; i++) 
{
NSLog(@"Playlist : %@", [[playlists objectAtIndex:i] valueForProperty: MPMediaPlaylistPropertyName]);
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Playlist can be explored like this:

```
MPMediaQuery *myQuery = [[MPMediaQuery alloc] init];

arrayOfPlaylist = [myQuery collections];

for (MPMediaPlaylist *playlist in arrayOfPlaylist) {
    NSLog (@"Playlist :%@", [playlist valueForProperty: MPMediaPlaylistPropertyName]);
    NSArray *songs = [playlist items];
    for (MPMediaItem *song in songs) {
        NSString *strSongTitle =
            [song valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
        NSLog (@"Title : %@", strSongTitle);
    }
}
```

Comment: that's show alot of whole songs from Library. I only want to show Playlist name bro. How could i?

Comment: Answer edited : NSLog (@"Playlist :%@", [playlist valueForProperty: MPMediaPlaylistPropertyName]);

Comment: only return a lot of NULL value.