# Retrieve playlists' name from music app iOS swift

Tags: swift, swift3, ios10

I'm trying to retrieve user's playlists' name from Music app in swift.

I trying this way

```
let myMediaQuery = MPMediaQuery.playlists().collections
```

Though [How to retrieve Playlist from iPod Library in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14052893/how-to-retrieve-playlist-from-ipod-library-in-ios) seems like have an answer, it doesn't work in Swift

Answer (score 7):

```
let myPlaylistsQuery = MPMediaQuery.playlists()
            let playlists = myPlaylistsQuery.collections

            for playlist in playlists! {
                print(playlist.value(forProperty: MPMediaPlaylistPropertyName) ?? "No name")

            }
```

This should work